# Where do you set preferredDisplayMode for UISplitViewController?

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller

I'd like to create a "slide-out-menu" for a portrait application on iOS 9 that allows pan gestures to switch between modes.

I would like it to switch between the modes "Hidden - The secondary view controller is displayed onscreen and the primary view controller is off screen" and "Overlay - The secondary view controller is onscreen and the primary view controller is layered on top of it."

According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISplitViewController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISplitViewController/displayMode), I need to set preferredDisplayMode for the UISplitViewController. Can somebody tell me where to modify this property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you created a splitViewController and set that as the rootViewController in your `AppDelegate`.

In `viewDidLoad` of the splitViewController do

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{[super viewDidLoad];
masterVC = [[MasterViewController alloc] init];
detailVC = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
NSArray *vcArray = @[masterVC, detailVC];
self.viewControllers = vcArray;
self.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAutomatic;
self.presentsWithGesture = YES;
self.preferredPrimaryColumnWidthFraction = .10;
self.delegate = (id)self;}
```

It will work for sure I have tested it.  MasterViewController is the primary viewController and DetailViewController is the secondaryviewController.

Note: In iOS 8 and later, you can use the UISplitViewController class on all iOS devices; in previous versions of iOS, the class is available only on iPad.

Comment: After doing a ton of research on this design, I realized that most apps incorporating this feature do so manually. I've seen a lot of examples that utilize the SWRevealViewController library. However, I wanted my master view to scroll over my detail view. Most importantly, I found that the preferredDisplayMode property of the UISplitViewDelegate is only acknowledged on regular sized devices, not compact. Therefore setting it to PrimaryOverlay did nothing. Since I did not specify a device in my question, I'll keep this answer marked because it might help people developing for iPads.

Comment: Hi @Andrew Kima to my understanding UISplitViewController works as we expect in iPhone 6+and iPads but when it comes to smaller display phones I recommend using your custom views. Here is what apple says **In iOS 8 and later, you can use the UISplitViewController class on all iOS devices; in previous versions of iOS, the class is available only on iPad.**

Comment: Exactly, I would have to design custom elements and animations w/constraints from scratch. Since I'm not ready to do that, I'm deciding to go with the tabbed application layout. Hopefully Apple adds more support for this design in Xcode 8 and iOS 10.